# Pagetransition before next page in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there any way to archive a page transition that fits the following requirements:

- I want to show a page transition when a page changes
- The page transition should finish before the next page loads/shows
- The page transition should run X seconds
- The page transition is a component placed in `_app.js`

Currently, I do this in a gruesome way.
In NuxtJS, it is possible to archive it via the Javascript Hooks. https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-transition

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Next.js has no built-in, easy way to do this, like Nuxt.js does. You could look into external libraries that could help with that, e.g, [framer-motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) and [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/)).

Comment: It is not about the animations themselves. I know both libs. It´s more the handling of the routing. Then It is possible to run the animation before the next page enters. At the moment, I use a Link component that runs the animation and then afterward pushed the new route. I was just wondering If there is a nice way like in nuxt. Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe worth having a look at [`next/router`'s events](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents) in that case. Could even listen to these in `_app`.

Comment: I did, but there is no event that fits my requirements or I did not use it right. The transition must be ready before the new page enters. And in the case of `routeChangeStart` you saw the content changing while the animation was running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook into Next.js Router events, but you can not set how much time the transition should take.

E.g. if you want the transition to be 3 seconds:

- if the Next.js transition takes 1 second, you can wait 2 seconds, but
- if the Next.js transition takes 4 seconds, you can't do anything about it.

And you can not know for sure how long the Next.js transition will take.

#### custom "routing"

Anyway, if you rely on the Next.js transition never taking more time than your animation, you would have to "store" the old page view somehow, and show it instead of the new page as long as the animation runs.

From Next.js perspective the new page should be shown. I think this would not work with Next.js routing, you would have to do the "routing" (display of content depending on the url) yourself, I guess. E.g. design your App to always have something like two pages at once, one is shown, one is hidden and might be loading. Then you can switch between these two pages whenever you want.

You might want to have a look at the experimental feature [React "Suspense"](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) (I don't know, I haven't used it).

#### wait before routing

If you want to wait a while before the transition starts, you might do something like this:

```
const startAnimation = () => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        console.log('...animate...');
        
        setTimeout( resolve, 3000 ); // <-- replace this line with your animation, and call resolve() when finished
    } );
};

const routerWrapper = {
    push: ( url ) => {
        startAnimation().then( () => {
            console.log('Next.js routing starts...');
            Router.push( url );
        })
    }
};

// ...

routerWrapper.push( newUrl ); // <-- this instead of Router.push( newUrl )
```

#### stop animation when routing completed

If you want to start an animation when `Route.push()` is called, and stop it when the Next.js transition is completed, you can use [Next.js routerevents](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents), e.g.:

```
export default function App( props: AppProps ) {
    const { Component, pageProps } = props;
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const routeChangeStart = (url, { shallow }) => {
            console.log('start animation');
        };

        const routeChangeComplete = (url, { shallow }) => {
            console.log('stop animation');
        };

        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart);
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', routeChangeComplete);

        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeStart', routeChangeStart);
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', routeChangeComplete);
        }
    }, [])

    // --
    return (
        <Component { ...pageProps } />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally done this yet, but it looks like you can do something like this with Framer Motion.

Destructuring props from the router in your main App component

```
function App({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
```

Then you can use the AnimatePresence component from Framer Motion to animate the route load and exit. You said you were familiar with the library in the comments so I won't talk about that component but here is what you add to the motion.div within the AnimatePresence component

```
<motion.div key={router.route}>
```

Below I will link a good article on how to do it and a good repo to use as an example. I did not write either of these but they are quite useful and descriptive.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-interactive-animations-and-page-transitions-to-a-next-js-web-app-with-framer-motion/#step-3-adding-page-transitions-with-framer-motion-to-a-next-js-app

https://github.com/colbyfayock/my-rick-and-morty-wiki/commit/3c1455370f750ff86b75a3b3edc446ebe553bf5b